# How to extract value from json in Postgress based on a key pattern?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.6

In Postgres v9.6.15, I need to get the SUM of all the values using text patterns of certain keys.

For example, having table "TABLE1" with 4 rows:

```
       |group  |col1
======================================
Row #1:|group1 |{ "json_key1.id1" : 1 }
Row #2:|group1 |{ "json_key1.id2" : 1 }
Row #3:|group1 |{ "json_key2.idX" : 1 }
Row #4:|group1 |{ "not_me" : 2 }
```

I'd like to get the int values using a pattern of the first part of the keys ( "json_key1" and "json_key2" ) and SUM them all using a CASE block like so:

```
SELECT table1.group as group,
  COALESCE(sum(
    CASE
    WHEN table1.col1 = 'col1_val1' THEN (table1.json_col->>'json_key1.%')::bigint
    WHEN table1.col1 = 'col1_val2' THEN (table1.json_col->>'json_key2.%')::bigint
    ELSE 0::bigint
  END), 0)::bigint AS my_result
FROM      table1 as table1
GROUP BY  table1.group;
```

I need "my_result" to look like:

```
       |group  |my_result
======================================
Row #1:|group1 |3
```

Is there a way to collect the values using regex or something like that. Not sure if I am checking the right documentation ( https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html ), but I am not finding anything that can help me to achieve the above OR if that is actually possible..

Comment: what if col1 contains more then one key matching the pattern?

Comment: Good point. But, the use case I am looking into won't have that situation. So for now, I will just apply the text pattern I described originally. Thanks anyways for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_each_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) in a lateral join to get pairs `(key, value)` from json objects:

```
select 
    group_col as "group",
    coalesce(sum(case when key like 'json_k%' then value::numeric end), 0) as my_result
from table1
cross join jsonb_each_text(col1)
group by group_col
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=cb398de09c682cdedba9f5819c1dbb8c)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot @klin.